# How to find a basis for $\mathcal{W} \in \mathbb{R}^5$

Tags: linear-algebra

A problem I'm working on states:

> Let $\mathcal{W}$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^5$ defined by $$\mathcal{W} = \{(n_1, n_2, n_3, n_4, n_5) \in \mathbb{R}\ | n_1 = 3n_2 + n_3, n_2 = n_5, n_4 = 2n_3\} $$
>   Find a basis for $\mathcal{W}$.

I know that in order to find a basis, I have to find a set of vectors that satisfy these two conditions: (1) they span $\mathcal{W}$ and 
(2) they are linearly independent, but I don't even have so much as a clue where to begin from the given definition of $\mathcal{W}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take an arbitrary element of $\mathcal{W}$, call it $(n_1, \ldots,n_5)$, and "substitute in" the constraints that you know must be satisfied.
For example you know $n_1 = 3n_2 + n_3$, so you can rewrite your vector as $(3n_2 + n_3, n_2, n_3, n_4, n_5)$. Do this with the other two constraints so that your vector is written in terms of only two of the original components. This general form should show you how to write any such vector of $\mathcal{W}$ as a linear combination of two particular vectors.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm beginning to see how to tackle this problem. But another question I have is how to prove that this set of vectors spans $\mathcal{W}$. I'm familiar with how to prove that two sets of vectors are linearly independent, but I'm not so sure when it comes to proving the span.

Comment: @D. Ashton For that you can rewrite W as given in my answer.

Comment: @Deepakms I see, but I would like to know what the general technique would be to prove that a set of vectors spans a vector space

Comment: @D. Ashton In many cases you can do this by contradiction. Assume that the given set B does not span   W. Thus there exist an element a in W that is not a linear combination of B. Thus a is linearly independent with elements of B. You can show that this is not the case.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Writing them in vector forms might help.

$$\begin{bmatrix} n_1 \\ n_2 \\ n_3 \\ n_4 \\ n_5\end{bmatrix}=n_2 \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} + n_3 \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

We know

$$\mathcal{W} = \{(3 n_5 + n_4/2, n_5, n_4 /2, n_4, n_5) \} $$ from the given conditions . We can now observe that (1/2 ,0,1/2,1,0) and (3,1,0,0,1) form a basis.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Let a vector $v\in W$ $$v(a,b,c,d,e)$$

thus

$$\begin{cases}
a=3b+c\\
b=e\\
d=2c \\
\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{cases}
a-3b-c=0\\
b-e=0\\
2c-d=0 \\
\end{cases}$$

Solvind the system you should obtain $v$ as a function of 2 parameters e.g. s and t.

Set s=1 and t=0 to find the first vector of the basis; s=0 and t=1 for the second.

**NOTE** it's not tha most effective way but it's a very good exercise to do